# IBM Watson Tradeoff Analytics Back-end service is not available

Tags: web, sapui5, watson, tradeoff, tradeoff-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Watson Tradeoff Analytics service into my external project to SAP WEB IDE, so I have downloaded the following example:

> github.com/dolevdotan/tradeoff-analytics-v2-vanilla-nodejs

Inside the Service on Bluemix I got the following credentials
[generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82fEl.png)

I put this credentials [inside app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjfcS.png)

I'm running my service and it's good at the beggining, but in case of pressed button "Help Me Decide" and the following error appears:

> Oops! Something went wrong
>   Back-end service is not available. Please try again later.

The most interesting is now! If I run the following link with deployed official TradeOff Example:

> tradeoff-analytics-v2-demo.mybluemix.net/#cars

My own service will work as expected after that, without any errors. But I need to run this link first. Why so strange? What shall I do to correct it and avoid?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: I would be rather surprised if you get good answers here. You might better check if IBM has some forums around Bluemix/Watson on IBM dev works. Chances are **much** higher to find answers there. One starting point: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/topics/watson/

Comment: I saw one good answer for the similar topic, decided to try :) Thank you anyway!